# NSLog returning null instead of string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, nslog

`NSLog` is returning the output 'Null" instead of a string that I would have expected. I suspect that this is a problem with private instance variables and such, but since I am not familiar with Object-oriented programming I cannot determine the cause.

```
//The viewDidLoad method in MainGameDisplay.m:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc] init];
    [engine setPlayerName: viewController];
}
```

The string is entered by a `UITextField`, the property being

```
//ViewController.h
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PlayerNameTextView;
```

The method works fine and returns the correct string if `[engine setPlayerName: self]` is placed into `ViewController`, but anywhere outside the location that `*PlayerNameTextView` is causes this problem.

```
//Engine.m
@implementation Engine
{
    ViewController *firstPage;
}

NSString *Player;

-(void) setPlayerName: (ViewController *) name
{
    Player = [[name PlayerNameTextView] text];
    NSLog(@"%@", Player);
}
```

Comment: Where is the problematic NSLog??

Comment: And `Player` is declared in the implementation, which makes it some sort of a C global or static, I think.  So I don't know how you expect to reference it elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is that NSLog(@"%@", Player); is returning null

Comment: Set a breakpoint right before your NSLog and I suspect you'll see "`Player`" truly **is** null.  Also, please follow objective C convention and start your variables with lower case letters (e.g. "`player`", not "`Player`").

Comment: You might also want to NSLog "name", at the same time that you log "Player".

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` return type is `void` as you can see [in it's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html). There is no reason to expect any return value for a call to it, since it does not return anything.

Comment: By "return", I think @Sina is saying the console output is stating "`<null>`".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 'name' is properly initialized. Try putting an assert(name != nil) right before the NSLog. Or better yet, set a breakpoint at the NSLog and inspect the variables.

Another suggestion: Why not make the method -(void) setPlayerName:(NSString*)name? This is more straightforward than passing around pointers to view controllers, and would be easier to debug.

Comment: Better to make sure that "name" isn't nil.  We already know that "Player" is nil, and assert(Player != nil) adds no information.

Comment: This can't be the reason because if I run setPlayerName in ViewController itself, the program works perfectly.